# Data Validation Error from Filter Formula

Tags: excel

I want to build a dynamic data validation list based on a region one chooses. I have a list of branch names and a list of region names in columns A and B, respectively. Moreover, someone will write the region name in cell F2, and this will make the data validation drop down, found in F3, match every branch name associated with the chosen region name. In cell F3, I have the following formula which lists out all associated branch names:

```
=IF($F$2="","All",UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,B:B=$F$2)))
```

My issue is that when I want to put this formula inside a data validation list, I get an error stating "The Source currently evaluates to an error." Is there a way to fix this error, or does the data validation not accept Filter formulas?

[image: DV Example]

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FILTER()` function will not work to data validation list. You can use `#` operator after cell reference to refer spilled results by `FILTER()` function. Try the following in data validation formula-

```
=$F$3#
```